# Whats the difference of functions and methods in Go?

Tags: function, methods, go

I am trying to get started with Go and the [documentation](http://golang.org) is very good. What I did not find in the documentation is the difference between functions and methods.

As far as I understand at the moment: functions are "global", which means I do not have to import a package to use functions, they are always there. Methods are bound to packages. Is this correct?

Comment: The terms "method" and "function" are just historical conventions.  The plain language implies "how" versus "what" which is not the case, and therefore confusing.  We might believe "function" is mathematical, but that's also not the case, and therefore confusing. 

The truth is "method" was just adopted from OO languages as being associated with a particular type, while "function" was adopted from procedural languages where the function is free-standing.  I think you can see those simple explanations hold in go: method is invoked on a type, function is not.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

> As far as I understand at the moment: functions are "global", which means I do not have to import a package to use functions, they are always there. Methods are bound to packages. Is this correct?

No, that's not correct. There are just a couple of functions from the [builtin](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/) package which are always available. Everything else needs to be imported.

The term "method" came up with object-oriented programming. In an OOP language (like C++ for example) you can define a "class" which encapsulates data and functions which belong together. Those functions inside a class are called "methods" and you need an instance of that class to call such a method.

In Go, the terminology is basically the same, although Go isn't an OOP language in the classical meaning. In Go, a function which takes a receiver is usually called a method (probably just because people are still used to the terminology of OOP).

So, for example:

```
func MyFunction(a, b int) int {
  return a + b
}
// Usage:
// MyFunction(1, 2)
```

but

```
type MyInteger int
func (a MyInteger) MyMethod(b int) int {
  return a + b
}
// Usage:
// var x MyInteger = 1
// x.MyMethod(2)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that "Go isn't an OOP language". Go IMHO just favors composition over inheritance so much that it provides extra syntatic sugar for the former and has gotten rid of the latter completely.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Imho, part of the OOP paradigm is also subclassing + type hierarchies. That's just not possible with Go (luckily!). Sure, Go provides other ways (i.e. embedding) to solve similar problems, but they are no 1:1 replacement. But let's stop the terminology-bikeshedding :D

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it! A missing piece was, that methods are always used in conjunction with a type.

Comment: @tux21b thank you for the examples. One problem, your method contains an `invalid operation: a + b (mismatched types MyInteger and int)`. In order for this to work you would need to cast either `a` to be an `int` or `b` to be a `MyInteger`. For example: `return int(a) + b` or `return a + MyInteger(b)`. In the second case, you would need to change the return value type in the method signature to be `MyInteger` instead of `int`. [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/tVlSCnkbx5)

Comment: I would point out the sentence states:  "Go isn't an OOP language in the classical meaning" not that it is not an OOP language

Comment: Go isn't a classic OOP language. Forget about encapsulation, polymorphism, and inheritance which you can implement in Go (even though there is no embedded into a language mechanism for easy implementation of these characteristics). Think of **Object** oriented programming. Object in this sentence is a **class** and since in Go function is a first-class citizen and they can exist without being a part of the class, you cannot call Go as a classic OOP language

Comment: So there are two ways to look at OOP. The original definition had nothing to do with classes or inheritance. Whether or not Alan Kay would consider Go an OO language is not entirely sure, because it misses the "extreme late binding of things" part. For the rest Kay said the important concept was objects passing messages. Go does that, well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqZQBmNVhBw <- A good talk about this. If you choose to follow Bjarne Stroustrup's OOP, then sure, classes, inheritance, etc.

Answer (score 31):

Tux's answer is great, but I want to augment it with the usage of Go's methods with `struct`s (because this is where I used it often). So let's assume you want to build something to calculate various methods on triangles. You start with a `struct`:

```
type Triangle struct {
    a, b, c float64
}
```

and then you would like to add some functions to calculate the perimeter and square:

```
func valid(t *Triangle) error {
    if t.a + t.b > t.c && t.a + t.c > t.b && t.b + t.c > t.a {
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Triangle is not valid")
}

func perimeter(t *Triangle) (float64, error) {
    err := valid(t)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    return t.a + t.b + t.c, nil
}

func square(t *Triangle) (float64, error) {
    p, err := perimeter(t)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    p /= 2
    s := p * (p - t.a) * (p - t.b) * (p - t.c)
    return math.Sqrt(s), nil
}
```

And now you got your working program <kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ryAGg6DjY4)</kbd>. In this case your function takes a parameter (pointer to a triangle) and does something. In OOP word people might have created a class and then added methods. We can see our struct as kind of class with fields and now we add methods:

```
func (t *Triangle) valid() error {
    if t.a + t.b > t.c && t.a + t.c > t.b && t.b + t.c > t.a {
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Triangle is not valid")
}

func (t *Triangle) perimeter() (float64, error) {
    err := t.valid()
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    return t.a + t.b + t.c, nil
}

func (t *Triangle) square() (float64, error) {
    p, err := t.perimeter()
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }

    p /= 2
    s := p * (p - t.a) * (p - t.b) * (p - t.c)
    return math.Sqrt(s), nil
}
```

and we have a fully <kbd>[working example](https://play.golang.org/p/KUXHWY3Ymh)</kbd>.

Notice that it looks really like a method for objects.

Comment: Is there any functional difference between a function with a pointer argument vs a method?  Are methods just syntactic sugar?

Comment: If function can do all the stuffs like you listed above, i still don't understand  the point to use method

Answer (score 23):

They are explained in detail here - https://anil.cloud/2017/01/26/golang-functions-methods-simplified/

A function in Go follows the syntax:

```
func FunctionName(Parameters...) ReturnTypes...
```

Example:

```
func add(x int, y int) int
```

To execute:

```
  add(2,3)
```

A method is like a function, but attached to a type (called as receiver). The official guide states “A method is a function with a special receiver argument”. The receiver appears in between the func keyword and the method name. The syntax of a method is:

```
func (t ReceiverType) FunctionName(Parameters...) ReturnTypes...
```

Example:

```
func (t MyType) add(int x, int y) int
```

To execute:

```
type MyType string
t1 := MyType("sample")
t1.add(1,2)
```

Now lets bring pointers into the table. Go lang is pass by value, means fresh copies of the parameters are passed to each function/method call. To pass them by reference you can use pointers.

Syntax of function with pointer in argument/parameter list.

```
func FunctionName(*Pointers...,Parameters...) ReturnTypes...
```

Example

```
func add(t *MyType, x int, y int) int
```

To execute:

```
type MyType string
t1 := MyType("sample")
add(&t1,4,5)
```

Similarly for methods, the receiver type can be a pointer. Syntax of method with pointer (as receiver)

```
func (*Pointer) FunctionName(Parameters...) ReturnTypes...
```

Example

```
func (t *MyType) add(x int, y int) int
```

To execute:

```
type MyType string
t1 := MyType("sample")
t1.add(2,3)
```

Note that we can still write t1.add() to execute the method with a pointer receiver(even-though ‘t1’ is not a pointer) and Go will interpret it as (&t1).add(). Similarly a method with value receiver can be called using pointer too, Go will interpret p.add() as as (*p).add() in that case (where ‘p’ is a pointer). This is applicable only for methods and not for functions.

Methods with pointer receiver are very useful to get a “Java” like behavior where the method is actually modifying on the value to which the receiver points and not on a copy of it.

Comment: just wondering, that would defeat the purpose as the whole argument on immutability is not to modify the value?

Answer (score 0):

Go methods are similar to Go function with one difference, i.e, the method contains a receiver argument in it. With the help of the receiver argument, the method can access the properties of the receiver. Here, the receiver can be of struct type or non-struct type.

```
func(reciver_name Type) method_name(parameter_list)(return_type){
    // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer seems good to me. Along with that I would also like to add on it.

`Function` is something which is ***invoked from package***. Whereas `method` is also a ***function but invoked from particular type values***. And `values` is the return of functions.

For example:

1. `rightNow := time.Now()`

`time` --> package, `Now()` --> function because invoked by a package, `rightNow` is the `value` of `type` time.Time returned from Now() function.

2. `year := rightNow.Year()`

`rightNow` --> value, `Year()` --> `function` but since it is invoked by a `value` of some `type`(here time.Time), therefore it is called a `Method`. For easily identication Method has a reciever of that same type from which it is invoked.