# Parameter before the function name in Go?

Tags: go

I have seen some Go functions defined like this:

```
type poly struct {
    coeffs [256]uint16
}

func (p *poly) reset() {
    for i := range p.coeffs {
        p.coeffs[i] = 0
    }
}
```

Which you can later call as:

```
var p poly
p.reset()
```

I haven't seen this in other programming languages that I know. What's the purpose of `p *poly` in the reset function? It seems to be like a function parameter but written before the function name. Any clarification for it?

Comment: Read golang tour https://tour.golang.org/methods/1 will give you an insights to your question.

Comment: When you understand things, you should also be aware of addressability and how methods are called, which will allow you to understand when a `poly` value can and can't be converted to a `*poly` value; this is important because `poly.reset` requires a `*poly` receiver while you used `p.reset()`, where `p` has type `poly`, not `*poly`.

Comment: The fact that this question was downvoted and closed is a great example for why people hate asking questions on SO. There's nothing wrong with the question, the way it was written or anything of the sort. The linked duplicate answers the question, but there is nothing wrong with this besides that.

Comment: It’s a more like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031801/function-declaration-syntax-things-in-parenthesis-before-function-name/66607825#66607825

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It means that `reset()` is a method on `*poly`.

Comment: If you look closely, you are modifying the value of the `poly` in the reset function, in such cases, you need to pass the pointer reference not the value to access its actual address.