# Invalid Receiver Type - Possible to use with a struct of myType?

Tags: go, slice

I'm just trying different things to learn go and understand the structures of how it works. Currently playing around with slices and custom types.

I have the following code which works fine and as expected.

```
package imgslice

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
)

type imageData struct {
    position      int         // Image Number
    image         *image.RGBA // Image Store
    height        int         // Height In Pixels
    width         int         // Width In Pixels
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("Starting")

    lbl := &[]imageData{}
    println(lbl)

    InitImage(lbl, 3)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", lbl)


}

// Initalise the imageData arrray
func InitImage(l *[]imageData, images int) {
    var i int
    var newRecord imageData

    for i = 0; i < images; i++ {
        newRecord = imageData{position: i}

        *l = append(*l, newRecord)

    }

    return
}
```

I'm trying to re-write the InitImage function to work as a method (i think that is the correct term). But I get the error:

> invalid receiver type *[]imageData ([]imageData is not a defined type)

(edit: Error is on the `func (l *[]imageData) InitImageNew(images int) {` line)

The only reason I want to do this is a) learning to see if it can be done and b) stylistically I think I prefer this do having the slice as an extra argument.

```
func (l *[]imageData) InitImageNew(images int) {
    var i int
    var newRecord imageData

    for i = 0; i < images; i++ {
        newRecord = imageData{position: i}

        *l = append(*l, newRecord)

    }

    return
}
```

Looking at this answer: [Function declaration syntax: things in parenthesis before function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031801/function-declaration-syntax-things-in-parenthesis-before-function-name)

It seems like it should be possible - however this answer seems to say it's not possible: [Golang monkey patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079225/golang-monkey-patching).

Is it possible to rewrite this so I could do

```
lbl := &[]imageData{}
lbl.InitImageNew(4)
```

Comment: A receiver has to be a defined type. `[]Type` is not a defined type. You can define it: `type ArrImageData []imageData` and use `*ArrImageData` as receiver.  But then you have to convert []imageData to ArrImageData to call the method.

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer I've solved it now thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only defined methods on *named types* (or pointers to named types). `[]Type` is a *compound type*. You could make it a named type by defining it:

```
type TypeSlice []Type
```

And then define methods on it.

This is covered in [the spec section on types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).

Comment: Fair, pointers are treated differently than any other compound type which could trip up some users. Updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

This question was the top one for my search, so i'll add what my issue was:
I had `type MyType = struct {` (with the equal sign) as the root cause. Removing equal sign helped.

Comment: Yes, if you get this error even for non-compound types, check your type declaration. If it contains an equals try removing it.

For example change `type MyType = struct { name string }` to `type MyType struct { name string }`.