# Should I define my funcs with a pointer to the struct or just on the struct?

Tags: pointers, go, function-pointers

In go I seem to have two options:

```
foo := Thing{}
foo.bar()

foo := &Thing{}
foo.bar()


func (self Thing) bar() {
}

func (self *Thing) bar() {
}
```

What's the better way to define my funcs with self Thing or with self *Thing?

Edit: this is not a duplicate of the question about methods and functions. This question has to do with Thing and &Thing and I think it's different enough to warrent it's own url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the difference of functions and methods in Go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263546/whats-the-difference-of-functions-and-methods-in-go)

Comment: ["Pointers vs. values in parameters and return values"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values/23551970#23551970) talks about some related issues.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this item from [the official FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers):

> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
>   these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
>   very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
>   above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
>   method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
>   the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
>   value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the
>   receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps
>   act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for
>   instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must
>   still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies
>   the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is
>   called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of
>   passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.
>
> By the way, pointer receivers are identical to the situation in Java,
>   although in Java the pointers are hidden under the covers; it's Go's
>   value receivers that are unusual.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a
>   big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer
>   receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have
>   pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is
>   consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on
>   method sets for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value
>   receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires
>   a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a clear answer but they're completely different. When you don't use a pointer you 'pass by value' meaning the object you called it on will be immutable (modifying a copy), when you use the pointer you 'pass by reference'. I would say more often you use the pointer variety but it is completely situational, there is no 'better way'.

If you look at various programming frameworks/class libraries you will see many examples where the authors have deliberately chosen to do things by value or reference. For example, in C# .NET this is the fundamental difference between a struct and a class and types like `Guid` and `DateTime` were deliberately implemented as structs (value type). Again, I think the pointer is more often the better choice (if you look through .NET almost everything is a class, the reference type), but it definitely depends on what you wish to achieve with the type and/or how you want consumers/other developers to interact with it. Your may need to consider performance and concurrency (maybe you want everything to be by value so you don't have to worry about concurrent ops on a type, maybe you need a pointer because the objects memory footprint is large and copying it would make your program too slow or consumptive).